# I have confusion with this sentence. "I think, It will be one of the best tutorial course ever published here "

Tags: past-tense, future-constructions

Is it correct? "I think, It will be one of the best tutorial courses ever published here "

I am just confused a little bit. Because the sentence is starting with the future tense and has had " ever published " participle form or Past form. It's a little confusing. Can I place two different tenses in the same sentence? Or You can suggest to me to learn about something.

Comment: The speaker is currently looking forwards to a future time when he can look back on the past, hence the mixed tenses. For example: "I **think** that this **will be** one of the best decisions that I **have ever made**."

Comment: No comma after think, don't capitalize "it".

Comment: Also _courses_ must be plural. The sentence "I think it will be one of the best tutorial courses ever published here" is perfectly good English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase **ever published** means "published at any time". The word **published** is an adjective formed from the *past participle* of the verb; it is not a tensed form of the verb.

P.S. You can think of the past participle form of the verb (and adjectives formed from it) as being *disconnected from time*. The participle form refers to a timeless *state*. The state becomes located in time only when the participle form is yoked to a tensed form of the verb.

> The book *was* published in 1910.
>
> The book *will be* published next year.
>
> The newspaper *is* published daily.
>
> The newspaper *will have been* published more than ten thousand times when
>   publication ceases  next spring.
>
> Only five issues *had been* published when the magazine was
>   discontinued.

Comment: I like this answer (except for a quibble about whether *published* is an adjective), but it might address the obvious transposition to a **tensed verb**: *It will be one of the best tutorial courses the company **has** ever **published** here.” The present perfect sounds fine to me, while dropping the *has* to get to the simple past doesn't.

Comment: Do you consider both "ever published" and "the company has ever published" to be reduced clauses, the first in the passive, the second in the active, voice?

Comment: The active voice *the company has ever published* is a clear analog to *that the company....*, but I don't think *that was ever published* works with the future tense in the independent clause (or with the adverb *ever*, for that matter). The simple past (here in the passive) talks about some unknown but fixed past publication, which clashes with a future point of publication. I like your analysis of *published* as a nonfinite verb form acting as a modifier. You can transpose to the passive via *that has ever been published*, but you can't drop the *that*.

Comment: *This will be the best tutorial ever written* (idiomatic) vs. *This will be the best tutorial that was ever written* (marginal?).

Comment: Yes, but maybe it's just me. What's the antecedent for *that*? Doesn't it have to be *tutorial*? It's possible that the tutorial hasn't been written yet as it's to be the best in the future, but that clashes with syntactically with a tutorial that was written. It's clear that the sentence means *This will be the best tutorial of **any** that was ever written*, but to me it doesn't quite say that. Notice that this seems OK if we get rid of an antecedent with a dummy: *It will be thus as it **was** ever so*.